# Python redirecting output from an LSF command

Tags: python, lsf

I am trying to run an LSF command , 'bjobs' inside a python code using subprocess and I am unable to get the output into a variable

Ways I have already tried and failed are as follows:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['bjobs'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print proc.stdout.read() ## Not working

stdout,stderr = subprocess.Popen(['bjobs'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()

print stdout # prints empty line
```

I do not want to redirect that to a physical file.

So please help me to find a way to directly capture them to a variable

Comment: I am expecting to capture the "No unfinished job found" message when you run the bjobs command while there are no pending jobs.

Comment: Have you tried printing stderr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by a comment above, the "No unfinished job found" message is printed to stderr:

```
[~]$ bjobs > /dev/null
No unfinished job found
[~]$ bjobs >& /dev/null
[~]$
```

If you want all `bjobs` output you should redirect subprocess stderr to stdout:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["bjobs"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
print proc.stdout.read()
```